# How to update a CakePHP in windows?

Tags: php, cakephp, ftp

I am working for the first time with CakePHP. I had never used it until today.
I am asked to just add a `<script></script>` tag to some pages of an already existing project. How do I do it? Please note that (I think) I cannot use the syntax `echo $this->Html->script('//...')` as this particular script tag must include `id` and some other parameters to work.

I guessed I had to modify the **View**s, just adding the script tag at the end of the content, but that did not work... I am working on a local file to then upload the file via ftp to a server. And after adding the tag to some pages, I saw no difference... Indeed, there was no script tag.

So I thought maybe I had to compile the code or something. That is when I found out about `cake bake`. I am working on a Windows PC (I usually use an Ubuntu machine, but I had no choice in this internship...) and I cannot access the server via SSH or so, just FTP.

I have a `cake.bat` file with this in:

```
@echo.
@echo off

SET app=%0
SET lib=%~dp0

php -q "%lib%cake.php" -working "%CD% " %*

echo.

exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

So do I have to download all the code, install php(-cli) in my machine, run this script and then reupload the whole thing? I could switch to my personal Ubuntu computer if that makes this easier.

Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: What is the version of cakephp you are using?

Comment: @urfusion Cake v2.0

Comment: if you want it to add on all page either create a js file and include that in header or footer, or direct add JS into header or footer. And if you want it to add on particular page then visit to the page and add it.
header and footer normally found under `app\View\Elements`. and rest of pages can be found `app\View\view_name`